# Rails How to rollback and render at a same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to render json and then raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, can we do it.

Scenario is like Api got called and after some operation something failed we need to let api users know what is the error and also rollback the operation performed.

Tried this

```
render json: response, status: status
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
```

This is raising an error "**ActiveRecord::Rollback: ActiveRecord::Rollback**"

Is there any other way to do it

Comment: May be this helps https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html

Comment: @Salil need both things together to work one after another

Comment: It says `ActiveRecord::Rollback is the only exception that won't be passed on by ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`

Comment: Can I ask why you want tot rollback instead of validating / preventing the operation in the first place? You would save yourself the DB calls, making it more scalable, and also reduce complexity. What is the action that you're looking to revert?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the error in an instance variable. Rollback the transaction if there is an error, and then render the error message. For example:

```
def your_action
  YourModel.transaction do
    @error = do_something
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if @error
  end

  return render json: { error: @error }, status: :bad_request if @error
  return render json: { data: "success" }, status: :ok
end

private

def do_something
  return :error01 if not operation1
  return :error02 if not operation2
  return :error03 if not operation3
  return nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to create a preview of how the database will be with the changes and then rollback, I think the best way is to use a around_action filter.

This was the example from the Rails Guides:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters

```
class ChangesController < ApplicationController
  around_action :wrap_in_transaction, only: :show

  private
    def wrap_in_transaction
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        begin
          yield
        ensure
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

you can go like this:

```
# app/controllers/your_controller.rb

def your_api_endpoint
  YourModel.transaction do
    # your operation 
    
    if something.save! # here `something` is an object of YourModel
      render status: :success, json: { message: "Successfully done." }
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: { message: "Something went wrong." }
    end
  end
end
```

It'll automatically rollback your data.
Thanks :)

Comment: This code does not trigger a rollback. It just wraps the whole thing in a transaction.

Comment: @max, I don't think show. You can check this [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Yeah this still only triggers a rollback after your edit if the record is invalid. Its not guaranteed to trigger a rollback like what you want if you are displaying a preview.